# Fan always on and overheating problems on HP G62

Tags: ati, cpu, overheating

I have a HP G62 with i5 processor, 4G Ram and ATI HD 5470. Started using Ubuntu 4 months ago, first was 11.10 and after 12.04. Everything worked perfectly until some weeks ago when my cpu fan became "crazy" and I mean by this always on, noise and overheating problems, for sure if I put a glass with water in some minutes will boil (and I mean it). There can be a bug in the last kernel or any other Ubuntu's official update?

And by the way

1. CPU fan is cleaned like a new born baby;
2. Used jupiter and all those stuff (lm-sensor, psensor...) - same problem;
3. Installing ATI drivers don't work very well. (interface laggy as HD 5470 isn't supported by Ubuntu) and I can't even open ATI Catalyst (error when I try to open it), more than this I always used open source drivers and as I said, worked perfectly (3d, effects).

Right now I'm back to Windows and everything is working perfectly but my main problem is that I get used with Ubuntu and kinda weird to use windows again. I want back my nice and almost perfect Ubuntu.

Comment: Probably, does using another kernel, old or new resolves your issue?

Comment: As I said, previous versions worked flawless. Anyway, I'll try again Ubuntu when they will update kernel version.

Comment: You can try a newer version at the mainline ppa instead of waiting until they show up in the update manager, but why don't you in the meantime uninstall the newest kernel and just leave the one that works .

Comment: Sorry, it's your ATI graphics card. Disable it in BIOS and use the Intel HD Graphics (works flawlessly in Ubuntu). If you don't have that option...think about getting a laptop from a manufacturer that has better support for Linux next time. (e.g. Lenovo).

Comment: When I purchased this laptop, approx. 1 year ago I never though I'm going to use Ubuntu, so for sure my next one will be compatible 100% with Ubuntu (related to drivers and everything else). I'll check my BIOS to see if there is any option to disable the main graphic card and use Intel HD. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @izx I don't have that option on my BIOS. Can this be done by using a code in Ubuntu?

Comment: As far as I know, it may be possible with [vgaswitcheroo](https://www.google.com/search?q=vgaswitcheroo+ubuntu+12.04&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=Palemoon:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) (read the AskUbuntu questions Google returns), but I don't think many have been successful. One solution is to install the FGLRX binary drivers, but you said you didn't want that.

Comment: If you are having trouble installing Catalyst (crashes, etc.), maybe you can open another question and we can try to help you install them?

Comment: FGLRX and Catalyst is not an option as my HD 5470 isn't here http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware. I'm going to search for vgaswitcheroo. Thanks once again.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Comment: This unanswered question is about EOL Ubuntu 12.04. VTC as `not reproducible`.